# remoteIO call back function is giving unstable buffer list

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-audio

every time callback function of the audio unit is being called, i get another number of samples which is strange because `NSLog(@"%ld",inNumberFrames);` gives me always 512.

when i do this :

```
NSLog(@"%li",strlen((const char *)(&bufferList)->mBuffers[0].mData));
```

i get numbers such as: 50 20 19 160 200 1 ...

which is strange. 
each call back, i have to get the full buffer 512 samples no ?

i know i dont get all needed samples because if i input a sin 2khz ,  i  get zero crossing of about 600, and if i put nothing, i g et the same.

to retrieve data i do :

```
static OSStatus recordingCallback(void *inRefCon, 
                                  AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *ioActionFlags, 
                                  const AudioTimeStamp *inTimeStamp, 
                                  UInt32 inBusNumber, 
                                  UInt32 inNumberFrames, 
                                  AudioBufferList *ioData)
{


    AudioBuffer buffer;

    buffer.mNumberChannels = 1;
    buffer.mDataByteSize = inNumberFrames * 2;
    //NSLog(@"%ld",inNumberFrames);
    buffer.mData = malloc( inNumberFrames * 2 );

    // Put buffer in a AudioBufferList
    AudioBufferList bufferList;
    bufferList.mNumberBuffers = 1;
    bufferList.mBuffers[0] = buffer;



    OSStatus status;
    status = AudioUnitRender(audioUnit, 
                             ioActionFlags, 
                             inTimeStamp, 
                             inBusNumber, 
                             inNumberFrames, 
                             &bufferList);  
    //checkStatus(status);
    NSLog(@"%li",strlen((const char *)(&bufferList)->mBuffers[0].mData));
    int16_t *q = (int16_t *)(&bufferList)->mBuffers[0].mData;
    for(int i=0; i < strlen((const char *)(&bufferList)->mBuffers[0].mData); i++)
    {
         ....
```

any help with this will save me days !
thanks .

Comment: Why are you using `strlen` with your buffers ???

Comment: so what should i use ? can you help me with retrieving the data in this line ?

Comment: Your buffers are a fixed size (inNumberFrames), so just iterate accordingly.

Comment: according to apple they are not, hence i should malloc them..

Comment: Yes, you malloc them, but their size does not subsequently change.

Comment: thanks a lot. so how should i get the length of my for(i) loop ?

Comment: You already know it - it's `inNumberFrames`

Comment: thanks a lot. i got it. its working much better ! another small thing. if i set " float bufferLength = 0.005;" it means that a full buffer is a data of 5msecond signal ? and if i dont set it, how much time of a signal buffer will be ?

Comment: Each callback tells you a number of samples.  The time is this number divided by the sample rate.  It can change between callbacks.

Comment: BUT i log numberOfFrames -got always 512. so is it not const ? so what bufferLength = 0.005 is doing anyway ? something here is missing. if buffer size stay 512 when i change buffer length, i am missing something here . because 44khz means 44 samples per 1ms , which means that for a 5ms buffer i will get 220samples. but i get 512................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A strlen() of the audio sample buffer is **not** related to the number of samples.  Instead, look at the number of frames given as the callback function's parameter.